# How exactly does EMMA mark the covered lines of code..?

Tags: java, code-coverage, emma

With regard to the working of EMMA..would like to know how EMMA marks the lines of code with respect to the source code. 
And is there a way to extract only the covered/marked lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EMMA does an instrumentation of the class files and the instrumentation code (additional byte code) is used to generate the [coverage reports](http://emma.sourceforge.net/samples.html).

It is not working on source files. Of course, the class files need "debug information", especially line numbers. But that's usually the case.

**Update**

It looks like, only the html report generator is capable of matching coverage results to line numbers. I wasn't able to get the same details for text or xml reports.

For a quick solution, I'd simply create the html reports and parse them with a html parser (xml parser *could* work as well) and extract the date from the html tables.

Alternatively, execute emmarun with the `-raw` option and look at the metadata and coverage files.

Comment: Agreed. Considering an example of a sample program, and after running EMMA on the code say line numbers 2,3,4 and 5 get executed. Now I would like to know how EMMA does this and the extract the same.

Comment: If my requirement is to extract the lines of code which have been marked covered, then can you please suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: EMMA will simply return line numbers, nothing else. You'd have to read the source files separatly and extract the lines of code. EMMA won't help there.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to access the line numbers? Could you please elaborate on that if there is one?

Comment: Could you please let me know if there is a way to parse information from the metadata or the sessiondata file(coverage.ES)?I don't know if I'm correct but the output of the instrumentation ought to contain the details I'm looking for right?I'm sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ans: u need to get the line numbers and then access source files separately. as told by Andreas_D
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to look at the Emma code base to determine exactly what they do. 
http://emma.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you want isn't "covered lines" but rather "covered code blocks" which start at some line/column, end at some other line/column, and may have holes in the middle for inner blocks of code.

Any system that offers coverage data based solely on line numbers won't provide with this kind of information.   You might be able to regenerate this information from the line numbers by the parsing the code and extracting all this data; that's a lot more work than it appears.  And it won't work if you have several statements in same line.

Our [Java Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/JavaTestCoverage.html) tool does collect "covered code blocks" in exactly the form I suggest; you can see this in the UI displays that show the code blocks and inner blocks.

There's a file exported by our tool that contains this "code block" information, and a mapping between the probes and the corresponding code blocks.  What you want would be pretty easy to extract from that file.